# Syntax Checker C++ Data Structure - Stack

Tags: c++, stack

Syntax Checker is a very common question of c++ programming using the data structure stack. However, this is the advanced level base on this question I found in a reference book. Here is the question:

Base on the question checking the string parentheses balance, the output is to print “Success” if all the brackets [] {} () are matched. Otherwise, print
"fail"

```
Sample Input:
{[()]()}[] //Output:Success
{}([[] //Output:3
{}([[]}] //Output:7
{}{(]} //Output:5
{}{](} //Output:4
( [43]( i++ ; ) ) { lol = 3 ; }  //Output:Success
```

My code as follow:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
#include<string>

bool arePair(char start, char end)
{
    if (start == '(' && end == ')') return true;
    else if (start == '{' && end == '}') return true;
    else if (start == '[' && end == ']') return true;
    return false;
}
bool areParanthesesBalanced(std::string exp)
{
    std::stack<char>  S;
    for (int i = 0; i < exp.size(); i++)
    {
        char c = exp.at(i);
        if (c == '(' || c == '{' || c == '[')
            S.push(exp.at(i));
        else if (c == ')' || c == '}' || c == ']')
        {
            if (S.empty()|| !arePair(S.top(), c)) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                S.pop();
            }
        }
    }
    return S.empty() ? true : false;
}
int main(){
    std::string input;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, input)) {
        if (areParanthesesBalanced(input))
            std::cout << "Success"<< std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Fail" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview. Looking forward to a review of this.

Comment: The comment in the code `//I dont know how to implement this part, so I just randomly output fail` indicates that this question is off-topic for the code review website.

Comment: edited. It's my bad to add that but then I am actually looking for some reviews...

Comment: Just removing the comment doesn't make the code less broken.

Comment: @Mast, they also changed the spec so that the code is now performing correctly.

Comment: @pacmaninbw *sigh* fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first things first, there are a couple of formatting points that would make your code a little nicer to read:

- Be consistent with your curly braces `{}`. In a couple of places, you have the opening brace on the same line as the thing before it whereas you don't in others.
- Be consistent with your naming too. I would name your stack `s` because it fits better with the camelCase used elsewhere.
- Spaces on your `#include <header>`s too please. It's just nitpicking but it's what most other programmers will be doing / used to.

That aside, lets get into the body of the code itself:

- `bool arePair(char, char)` is very verbose in it's definition. You could turn the entire function into a single boolean expression of the form:

```
return (start == '(' && end == ')')
    || (start == '{' && end == '}')
    || (start == '[' && end == ']');
```

An alternative would be to use a switch statement:

```
switch (start) {

case '(': return end == ')';
case '{': return end == '}';
case '[': return end == ']';

default:
    return false;
}
```

What you choose is a matter of preference. I would probably go for the switch approach, however, because to me it is clearer what is intended.

- `areParanthesesBalanced` is badly named. There is a typo in "parentheses" and parentheses refers specifically to () not {}, [] or <>. `areBracketsBalanced` would be more appropriate.
- One idea would be to pass `const std::string& exp` to the function rather than `std::string`. This prevents the program having to make a copy of the entire string in case you modify it.
- Your for loop `for (int i = 0; i < exp.size(); i++) { ... }` never actually makes use of the value of `i`. Instead you could use a range for like this `for (char c : exp)` which just gives you each character in turn.
- Your `else` is unnecessary because you've already returned execution from the function at that point.
- The line `return s.empty() ? true : false;` is bad because `stack<>::empty()` returns a boolean! Therefore, just use `return s.empty();`.

Overall this gives:

```
bool arePair(char start, char end)
{
    switch (start) {

    case '(': return end == ')';
    case '{': return end == '}';
    case '[': return end == ']';

    default:
        return false;
    }
}

bool areBracketsBalanced(const std::string& exp)
{
    std::stack<char>  s;
    for (char c : exp)
    {
        if (c == '(' || c == '{' || c == '[')
            s.push(c);
        else if (c == ')' || c == '}' || c == ']')
        {
            if (s.empty() || !arePair(s.top(), c))
                return false;
            s.pop();
        }
    }
    return s.empty();
}
```

### But...

That covers a lot of smaller points but having constants defining your pairs of brackets in multiple places seems messy. Here's one possible solution but there might well be a nicer one I haven't thought of:

```
int isBracket(char c)
{
    switch (c) {

    case '(': return  1;
    case ')': return -1;

    case '{': return  2;
    case '}': return -2;

    case '[': return  3;
    case ']': return -3;

    default:
        return 0;
    }
}

bool areBracketsBalanced(const std::string& exp)
{
    std::stack<char>  s;
    for (char c : exp)
    {
        if (isBracket(c) > 0) // Opening brackets
            s.push(c);
        else if (isBracket(c) < 0) // Closing brackets
        {
            if (s.empty() || isBracket(s.top()) + isBracket(c))
                return false;
            s.pop();
        }
    }
    return s.empty();
}
```

### Instead of printing fail...

You want to know the position of the failing bracket? Try changing the return type of `areBracketsBalanced` to `int`. You're already determining at what position it fails implicitly by returning false.

Comment: The case statement in the alternative arePair never returns true.